# What does 'required' in OpenAPI really mean

Tags: swagger, openapi

Given the following OpenAPI definition

```yaml
Person:
  required:
    - id
  type: object
  properties:
    id:
      type: string
```

Which of the below objects are valid? Only A, or A & B?

```
A. {"id": ""}
B. {"id": null}
C. {}
```

This boils down to the question whether "required = true" means "non-null *value*" or "*property* must be present".

The JSON schema validator at https://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/ says that B. be invalid because `null` doesn't satisfy the `type: string` constraint. Note that it doesn't complain because `id` is null but because `null` is not a string. BUT how relevant is this for OpenAPI/Swagger?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The `required` keyword in OpenAPI Schema Objects is taken from [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.5.3) and means:

> An object instance is valid against this keyword if **every item in the [`required`] array is the name of a property in the instance**.

In other words, `required` means **"property must be present", regardless of its value**. The `type`, `format`, etc. of the property value are separate constraints that are evaluated separately from `required`, but together as a combined schema.

In your example:

1. `{"id": ""}` is valid:

   - ✓ validates against `required`
   - ✓ the value `""` validates against `type: string`
2. `{"id": null}` is NOT valid:

   - ✓ validates against `required`
   - ✗ `null` does NOT validate against `type: string` (see the notes about nulls below)
3. `{}` is NOT valid:

   - ✗ does NOT validate against `required`

Note that `'null'` as a type is not supported in OpenAPI 2.0 but is [supported in OpenAPI 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48111459/113116), and 3.0 has [`nullable`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#fixed-fields-20) to handle nulls. So, `{"id": null}` is valid against this OpenAPI 3 schema:

```yaml
Person:
  required:
    - id
  type: object
  properties:
    id:
      # OAS 3.1
      type: [string, 'null']

      # OAS 3.0
      # type: string
      # nullable: true
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Not your fault that the JSON schema spec doesn't align well with the JavaScript/JSON notion of `null`.

Comment: @MarcelStör JSON Schema does have the `null` type, and a nullable schema can be defined as `{"type": ["string", "null"]}`. But OpenAPI does not support `type: null` and uses the `nullable` attribute instead.

Comment: what implication does this have on a patch request? I am thinking of any attribute could be present but doesnt have to since its a patch. And does it mean I would need 2 models for patch and post? Post requires all but patch kinda nothing?

Comment: @TheFool you'll need 2 models in that case. The POST model can be `allOf` of the PATCH model + the `required` list. [Example](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Swagger-Open-Source-Tools/how-to-have-different-required-fields-for-the-create-put-and/m-p/196699/highlight/true#M915)