# OAS3 misspelled or non-existent properties listed in required do not break validation of schema

Tags: schema, openapi

This schema object contains a `required` property that is not listed in its `properties`. I don't understand why validators like `editor.swagger.io` don't call this out as an invalid schema:

```
components:
  schemas:
    MyObject:
        type: object
        properties:
          id:
            type: string
          name:
            type: string
        required:
          - id
          - name
          - nonexistent
```

I can't find any reference to this phenomenon in the OAS3 documentation, so I don't know if this is consistently applied (but I have found two validators with this behaviour).

Comment: Related: [What does 'required' in OpenAPI really mean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45575493/113116)

Comment: @Helen according to that question there is no object that could pass validation with the above schema, but the reality is that really popular validators don't blink an eye. I want to know why.